# httpd serving files from vhosts instead of var/www

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

This is a noob question but I have been messing with it and still can't sort it. Apache is serving files from vhosts rather than var/www, which is what I have indicated in httpd.conf.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

I'm tryig to test my mod-wsgi installation and configuration, but even without that, this should work, and its not. I think I'm missing something small, but can't figure it out.

This is set to the same location as well:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Comment: Also, there is a file called server.conf that has info for the virtualhost container and it indicates that the DocumentRoot is var/vhosts . . . Is this overriding the directive in the httpd.conf?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: thanks. the question was why Apache was still serving files from the default directory, even though I had made changes to the httpd.conf file to indicate another location, but I figured it out. I literally just needed to restart the service, and now everything works.